# How to do Role-based Web API Authorization using Identity Server 4 (JWT)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4

This is all new to me and I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. I've got an IDP (Identity Server 4) set up, and I was able to configure a client to authenticate to it (Angular 6 App), and further more to authenticate to an API (Asp.Net Core 2.0). It all seems to work fine.

Here's the client definition in the IDP:

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "ZooClient",
                ClientName = "Zoo Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RequireConsent = true,

                RedirectUris           = { "http://localhost:4200/home" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:4200/home" },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:4200" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Phone,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Address,
                    "roles",
                    "ZooWebAPI"
                }
            }
```

I'm requesting the following scopes in the client: 
'openid profile email roles ZooWebAPI'

The WebAPI is set up as such:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddMvcCore()
            .AddJsonFormatters()
            .AddAuthorization();

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44317";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ApiName = "ZooWebAPI";    
            });


    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            policy.AllowAnyHeader();
            policy.AllowAnyMethod();
            policy.AllowCredentials();
            policy.WithExposedHeaders("WWW-Authenticate");
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

By using [Authorize] I was successfully able to secure the API:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            return new JsonResult(User.Claims.Select(
                c => new { c.Type, c.Value }));
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, if client is not authenticated, browser goes to IDP, requires authentication, redirects back with access token, access token is then used for API calls that are successfully made.

If I look at the Claims in the User object, I can see some information, but I don't have any user information. I can see the scopes, and etc, but no roles for example. From what I read, that is to be expected, and the API should not care about what user is calling it, but how would I go by restricting API calls based on roles? Or would that be completely against specs?

The IDP has an userinfo end point that returns all the user information, and I thought that would be used in the WebAPI, but again, from some reading, it looks like the intention is for that end point to be called from the client only.

Anyway, I would like to restrict Web API calls based on the roles for a specific user. Does anyone have any suggestions, comments? Also, I would like to know what user is making the call, how would I go by doing that?

JWT example:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I can learn from your information, I can tell the following.

You are logging in through an external provider: Windows Authentication.
You are defining some scopes to pass something to the token that indicates access to specific resources.

The User object you speak of, is the User class that gets filled in from the access token. Since the access token by default doesn't include user profile claims, you don't have them on the User object. This is different from using Windows Authentication directly where the username is provided on the User Principle.

You need to take additional action to provide authorization based on the user logging in.
There a couple of points where you can add authorization logic:

You could define claims on the custom scopes you define in the configuration of Identityserver. This is not desirable IMHO because it's fixed to the login method and not the user logging in.

You could use ClaimsTransformation  ( see links below). This allows you to add claims to the list of claims availible at the start of your methods. This has the drawback ( for some people an positive) that those extra claims are not added to the access token itself, it's only on your back-end where the token is evaluated that these claims will be added before the request is handled by your code.

How you retrieve those claims is up to your bussiness requirements.

If you need to have the user information, you have to call the userinfo endpoint of Identityserver to know the username at least. That is what that endpoint is intended for. Based on that you can then use your own logic to determine the 'Roles' this user has.

For instance we created an separate service that can configure and return 'Roles' claims based upon the user and the scopes included in the accesstoken.

[UseClaimsTransformation .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.claimstransformationappbuilderextensions.useclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-1.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1)

[UseClaimsTransformation .NET Full framework](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.Owin.ClaimsTransformation)